# How to Pass a Variable Between Batch and VBS?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have made a perfect square number finder that starts from 1 and the code is below. However, I need a way to pass variables between batch and vbscript (VBS has a better UI). I am stuck at this point, how do I send a variable between a batch and vbscript? If anything maybe have the vbscript print a number into a file then the batch script reads the file and the number in it then deletes it.

```
@echo off 
title Perfect Squares without paste to file
cls

set /a num=3
set /a num1=1
echo 1

:1
set /a num2=%num1%+%num%
echo %num2%
echo %num2%
set /a num1=%num2%
set /a num=%num%+2
goto 1
```

Comment: You can use command line arguments while calling the batch files to pass on the data from VBS

Comment: Please show the VBS part. Not clear, please elaborate do you need to pass from batch to VBS or from VBS to batch? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34321609/2165759) may be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a VBScript from a batch file like this (the parameter `//NoLogo` prevents the interpreter from printing the version/copyright banner all the time):

```
cscript //NoLogo C:\your.vbs 23
```

Use the [`Arguments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b05k8s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx<pre) property for receiving the argument (`23`) in the VBScript:

```vb
value = WScript.Arguments(0)
```

and pass a value back to the batch script via the return value:

```vb
WScript.Quit 42
```

**Example:**

VBScript code:

```vb
value = WScript.Arguments(0)
WScript.Quit value + 19
```

Batch code:

```
@echo off

cscript //NoLogo C:\your.vbs %1
echo %errorlevel%
```

Output:

```
C:\>batch.cmd 23
42

C:\>batch.cmd 4
23
```

---

If you need to pass text back and forth, passing the response back to the batch script becomes more complicated. You'll need something like this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%r in ('cscript //NoLogo C:\your.vbs %1') do set "res=%%r"
```

**Example:**

VBScript code:

```vb
str = WScript.Arguments(0)
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine str & " too"
```

Batch code:

```
@echo off

setlocal

for /f "tokens=*" %%r in ('cscript //NoLogo C:\your.vbs %1') do set "res=%%r"
echo %res%
```

Output:

```
C:\>batch.cmd "foo"
foo too

C:\>batch.cmd "and some"
and some too
```

---

On a more general note: why do you use batch/VBScript in the first place? PowerShell is far more versatile than both of them combined, and is available for any halfway recent Windows version.