# In a vbscript, how can i get the process id of the cmd.exe in which the vb script is running

Tags: vbscript, cmd, wmi, pid, terminate

within a vb script, I want to assign a variable with the process id of the cmd.exe in which the vb script is running. Is there any command?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34321609/2165759) should help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the example VB script procedure returning parent process caption and id:

```vb
GetParentProcessInfo sCaption, sProcessId

MsgBox "Parent Process Caption '" & sCaption & "'" & vbCrLf & "Parent Process Id '" & sProcessId & "'"

Sub GetParentProcessInfo(sCaption, sProcessId)
    With GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2:Win32_Process.Handle='" & CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("rundll32 kernel32,Sleep").ProcessId & "'")
        With GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2:Win32_Process.Handle='" & .ParentProcessId & "'")
            With GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2:Win32_Process.Handle='" & .ParentProcessId & "'")
                sCaption = .Caption
                sProcessId = .ProcessId
            End With
        End With
        .Terminate
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. 

I am new vb script.  I have to write a vbs that kills all the cmd.exe except the one in which the vb script is going to run. 

Below is the code which I was trying.

Comment: Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set a = WshShell.Exec(cmd /c "wmic process get parentprocessid,name|find WMIC") 
x = a.StdOut.ReadLine
Wscript.Echo x
pid = Right(x,4)
Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'cmd.exe' and ProcessID != &abc")
For Each item In colProcesses
  item.terminate()
Next

Comment: @bharathipriyaT please don't post this as the comments, but add all these details into your question by editing it. Describe how does your code works, what's wrong and what is the expected behavior. Then I may suggest some code.

Comment: This solution has the advantage that it doesn't use a console program. In former times I experienced big trouble when to many console programs were executed on a disconnected terminal server session (they had all been properly terminated).
rundll32 instead is a regular windows application (no console window shown), so this error will not appear.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to get a scripts parent process id.

```
Function GetParentPid()
    GetParentPid=GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2").ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process Where CommandLine Like '%" &Wscript.ScriptName& "%'").ItemIndex(0).ParentProcessId
End Function

Wscript.Echo GetParentPid()
```